# How to know the execution time in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scheduled-tasks, fork

Suppose that I have three script(a.sh b.sh c.sh) to be launched in a script called launcher.sh:

```
first=`date +%s`

./a.sh &
./b.sh &
./c.sh &

final=`date +%s`

executionTime=`echo "scale=3;($final - $first)/3600" | bc`

echo $executionTime
```

I know above script won't work because launcher.sh will finish immediately after launching a.sh, b.sh and c.sh. Launching a.sh, b.sh and c.sh without **"&"** is wasting time because they don't have to wait for each other.

Suppose that the execution time for them are 5 seconds, 10 seconds and 7 second respectively, how can I get 10 seconds as the overall execution time?

Answer (score 4):

Use `wait`:

```
first=`date +%s`

./a.sh &
./b.sh &
./c.sh &

wait

...
```

Quoting `help wait`:

> `wait: wait [id]`
>
> ```
> Wait for job completion and return exit status.
>
> Waits for the process identified by ID, which may be a process ID or a
> job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
> given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
> status is zero.  If ID is a a job specification, waits for all processes
> in the job's pipeline.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns the status of ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid option is
> given.
> ```

Comment: @Mat Thanks for teaching me something new about markdown.  (I was wondering why the change didn't have any effect.)

Comment: By the way can I ask for more? The manual says waits for currently active child processes, but is there any possibility child processes not the active? If the child process called sleep, is that a active process?

Comment: If it calls sleep, it's still considered active.

Comment: @MarcusThornton As mentioned by Johannes, it'd be _active_ even if you're invoking `sleep`.  Active refers to a running process here.

Comment: @MarcusThornton even _blocked_ (in process control terms) and _zombie_ processes will be considered active. Basically, every process that hasn't been scheduled to `stopped`(usually by sending `sigterm`) is.

Answer (score 2):

linux comes with the `time` command that is especiall designed for this exact usage. Just call `time yourscript`.

As your launcher script starts processes in the background, `time` alone isn't sufficient. As stated by @devnull, there is the `wait` command that blocks a call until all subprocesses have terminated.

There is an easy way to combine wait and time, without modifying your launcher script and without the need to manually stop the time:

```
time `./launcher.sh;wait `
```

should do the trick.

(tried this with a minimal example. as long as you execute the launcher + wait inside a subshell (using ``), this will work (but you loose otuput from the launcerh script if it does output something))

---

Minimal example:

test1.sh

```
./test2.sh &
```

test2.sh

```
sleep 10
```

Result:

> $ time `./test1.sh;wait`
>
> real    0m10.004s
>   user    0m0.001s
>   sys     0m0.001s

Comment: @devnull erm... have to agree on this. I'll edit this answer to refelct that plus provide a wokring solution.

Comment: I have tried the solution @JohannesH. mentioned using time and it didn't work.

Comment: @MarcusThornton See my edit. It's basically a combination of what devnull suggested and my original solution (so credit him, too). I tested this, it should work and is the most simple way to go IMHO.

Comment: test.sh: sleep 20 
test2.sh: ./test.sh &
time ./test2.sh;wait
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.001s
It seems to be not working

Comment: I tested this with 2 scripts: one does `sleep 10`, the other one calls the first one (and daemonized it using `&`of course). The command in my answer displayed 10sec runtime after 10 sec.

Comment: @MarcusThornton make sure to include those backticks, they are there  on purpose ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the backticks. In the case`./launcher.sh;wait `, who waits for whom?

Comment: It waits for ALL of them, whcih is the entire point. `wait` waits for any suprocess that is spawned. In this case, anything `./launcher.sh` or any of its childs (or grandchildren, and so on) spawns. The backticks are necessary to spawn the whole thing inside a subshell, otherwise the `;` would separate `time ./launcher.sh` and `wait`.

Comment: If you want to use this in your crontab file, which can mail you the output, you're probably going to want to use `time -p` instead of just `time`. `time -p` sends output to stderr. If necessary, you can use redirection, but `time` by itself will not be included in the output of the cron job necessarily.

Comment: I thought your time `./test1.sh & ;wait` would work. But it didn't. I thought it will wait for child, grand child and grand grand child process. Why can't I add a & in your technique?

Comment: @MarcusThornton Because in this case, .`/test1.sh` is spawned outside the subshell `wait` is in. Move the `./test1.sh & ;wait` part inside a script and it will work again.

Comment: @MarcusThornton `time \`./test1.sh & ;wait\`` results in a syntax error in my bash BTW...

Comment: What I talked about is time `./test1.sh & ;wait` will cause in a syntax error. I thought the command is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Just before exit your script write

```
echo $SECONDS
```

or to run your script in a terminal windows, type

```
$> time your_script
```