# How to get the execution time of child and offspring process in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, fork

I want to run test1.sh, test2.sh and test3.sh in background and record the execution time respectively. So I used the following commands.

```
time `./test1.sh & ; wait` > record_1
time `./test2.sh & ; wait` > record_2
time `./test3.sh & ; wait` > record_3
```

While the content in test1.sh could be going to call other script:

```
./other_test1.sh &
```

So test2.sh and test3.sh could call ./other_test2.sh & and ./other_test3.sh &

The reason I want to use wait is because test1.sh and others will fork child process, and I want the execution time to include the execution time of child and offspring processes. However it resulted in an error like:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `./test2 & ;wait'
```

I idea is in the backsticks part the **wait** command will wait for the background script like test1.sh to be terminated. I cannot figure out what's going wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810652/how-to-know-the-execution-time-in-linux) was the same and you were provided an answer.  Weren't you?

Comment: I think the previous question an this one is a little bit different. In the previous one I wanted to now the total execution time of the launcher.sh. So using wait to wait for test1.sh, test2.sh and test3.sh is OK. However in this question I want to record the each execution time of the test.sh which the launcher will call. After I asked the previous question I think it is better if I can get more detail of the execution time by getting each execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Since `&` and `;` are both list operators that separate commands and have equal precedence, you cannot use them together.  Doing so would be similar to using multiple conditional list operators together like `command1 && || command2`. It's a logical contradiction.

To get around this understandable constraint, you can use a sub shell `(...)` with `\` to continue the line.

```
time (./test1.sh & \ wait) &> record_1
time (./test2.sh & \ wait) &> record_2
time (./test3.sh & \ wait) &> record_3
```

Answer (score 0):

`&; wait` is not needed if you want to measure the execution time of test.sh. Additionally, you cannot redirect the time output only with `>`. Use this:
`bash -c 'time ./test1.sh' &> record_1`

So you may come to conclude with these lines:

```
bash -c 'time ./test1.sh' &> record_1
bash -c 'time ./test2.sh' &> record_2
bash -c 'time ./test3.sh' &> record_3
```